# error when Load Data from datagridview To textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have an error to load data from Datagridview to TextBox . Look at the picture below `https://s32.postimg.org/m28ardoat/Sans_titre.png`
My code :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick    
    Try
        If (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0) Then Return
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
        Dim id As String = DataGridView1(2, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT ClientID, ClientName, ClientAddress, ClientPhone, ClientCredit, ClientLastPay FROM client where client.ClientID = {0}", id))
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
        TextBox3.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2).ToString
        TextBox4.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString
        dt.Dispose()
        dt = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

by debugging the error in this line :`Dim id As String = DataGridView1(2, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value`
hope to help me !

Comment: You should make it easy for people to help you and at least translate the error message.

Comment: Actually, this is a repost of the same question you asked earlier today.